# Exercises on Dynkin Lemma and Monotone class Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, reference-request, monotone-class-theorem

I am trying to understand and to apply two fundamental theorems in probability and measure theory:

(a) Dynkin Lemma aka. $\pi/\lambda$ Theorem

(b) Monotone class theorem

W.r.t. (b) I had to solve some exercises in advanced books, where the hint "Use a monotone class argument" was given. 
Therefore, I am looking for books/lecture notes/... where I can find as much exercises as possible on the above theorems. 
Do you know of good sources?

Comment: Literally any introductory probability theory book.

Comment: Probably with martingales David Williams?

Comment: Unfortunately, the suggested literature doesn't provide sufficient insight on the results, mentioned in the question. It seems difficult, to find a good source especially on the MCT, containing statement, proof and exercises on that result.